# How to install drain in a wall above concrete foundation

Tags: concrete, walls, drain, foundation, sink

I am usual successful finding answers with enough searching but it seems I've hit a dead end here.

Just started a kitchen remodel in our 104 year old home. Looking to move our kitchen sink to an adjacent wall in the house.  The issue I'm coming up against is that it looks like the outside wall where I need to install the drain / vent stack is sitting on the far side of an 8-10" foundation wall.

How on earth would one tackle running a drain down to the floor below (unfinished basement) from here?

In the photos attached you can see the floor after removing the rotted flooring and can catch a glimpse of the top of the foundation.  The other pictures are for context of the wall location.  The sink would go directly underneath the window.

Any help would be appreciated.!

[image: top of foundation through the floor]

[image: door entry above foundation]

[image: wall]

[image: desired sink location]

Answer (score 1):

A few options:

- Run the drain pipe through the foundation (rent the appropriate rotary hammer/hole saw for this)
- Run it through the cabinetry (as NPM suggests)
- Build out the interior wall in front of this window and run the plumbing in there
- Build out something on the exterior and run the plumbing in there
- Build up the floor above your existing floor and run it through there

Running through the foundation may be the cleanest option, but I've seen all of these approaches deployed in various houses. Depends on your budget, skill, and preferences.

Comment: This list of options is much appreciated.  I think through the floor seems the most doable.  I could go through the foundation I think, but it's old and cramped overhead down there.

Answer (score 0):

Plan to run your plumbing after the fact, through the floor of the cabinet. As far as your vent, you'll have to plan to use a studer for the sink, and run the main venting elsewhere.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, do you think it is worth it to truly and connect it to a vent behind the cabinet and up through the wall instead of using the cheater vent?  The space for the vent is there, just the drain is a bother.

Thank you.

Comment: Absolutely. Real venting is ideal, studors can be done anyrime after.